# Getting name of attributes with Scrapy XPATH

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to get both keys and values of attributes of some tag in a XML file (using scrapy and xpath).

The tag is something like:

```
<element attr1="value1" attr2="value2 ...>
```

I don't know the keys "attr1", "attr2" and so on, and they can change between two elements. I didn't figure out how to get both keys and values with xpath, is there any other good practice for doing that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short version**

```
>>> for element in selector.xpath('//element'):
...     attributes = []
...     # loop over all attribute nodes of the element
...     for index, attribute in enumerate(element.xpath('@*'), start=1):
...         # use XPath's name() string function on each attribute,
...         # using their position
...         attribute_name = element.xpath('name(@*[%d])' % index).extract_first()
...         # Scrapy's extract() on an attribute returns its value
...         attributes.append((attribute_name, attribute.extract()))
... 
>>> attributes # list of (attribute name, attribute value) tuples
[(u'attr1', u'value1'), (u'attr2', u'value2')]
>>> dict(attributes)
{u'attr2': u'value2', u'attr1': u'value1'}
>>>
```

**Long version**

XPath has a [`name(node-set?)` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-name) to get node names ([an attribute is a node, an attribute node](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#attribute-nodes)):

> The ***name*** function returns a string containing a QName representing the expanded-name of the node in the argument node-set that is first in document order.(...) **If the argument it omitted**, it defaults to a node-set with the **context node** as its only member.

(source: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-name)

```
>>> import scrapy
>>> selector = scrapy.Selector(text='''
...     <html>
...     <element attr1="value1" attr2="value2">some text</element>
...     </html>''')
>>> selector.xpath('//element').xpath('name()').extract()
[u'element']
```

*(Here, I chained `name()` on the result of `//element` selection, to apply the function to all selected element nodes. A handy feature of Scrapy selectors)*

One would like to do the same with attribute nodes, right? But it does not work:

```
>>> selector.xpath('//element/@*').extract()
[u'value1', u'value2']
>>> selector.xpath('//element/@*').xpath('name()').extract()
[]
>>>
```

Note: I don't know if it's a limitation of `lxml/libxml2`, which Scrapy uses under the hood, or if the XPath specs disallow it. (I don't see why it would.)

What you can do though is use `name(node-set)` form, i.e. with a non-empty node-set as parameter. If you read carefully the part of the XPath 1.0 specs I pasted above, as with other string functions, `name(node-set)` only takes into account the **first node** in the node-set (in document order):

```
>>> selector.xpath('//element').xpath('@*').extract()
[u'value1', u'value2']
>>> selector.xpath('//element').xpath('name(@*)').extract()
[u'attr1']
>>>
```

Attribute nodes also have positions, so you can loop on all attributes by their position. Here we have 2 (result of `count(@*)` on the context node):

```
>>> for element in selector.xpath('//element'):
...     print element.xpath('count(@*)').extract_first()
... 
2.0
>>> for element in selector.xpath('//element'):
...     for i in range(1, 2+1):
...         print element.xpath('@*[%d]' % i).extract_first()
... 
value1
value2
>>>
```

Now, you can guess what we can do: call `name()` for each `@*[i]`

```
>>> for element in selector.xpath('//element'):
...     for i in range(1, 2+1):
...         print element.xpath('name(@*[%d])' % i).extract_first()
... 
attr1
attr2
>>>
```

If you put all this together, and assume that `@*` will get you attributes in document order (not said in the XPath 1.0 specs I think, but it's what I see happening with `lxml`), you end up with this:

```
>>> attributes = []
>>> for element in selector.xpath('//element'):
...     for index, attribute in enumerate(element.xpath('@*'), start=1):
...         attribute_name = element.xpath('name(@*[%d])' % index).extract_first()
...         attributes.append((attribute_name, attribute.extract()))
... 
>>> attributes
[(u'attr1', u'value1'), (u'attr2', u'value2')]
>>> dict(attributes)
{u'attr2': u'value2', u'attr1': u'value1'}
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to get both keys and values of attributes of some tag in a XML file (using scrapy and xpath).

You need `@*`, which means "any attribute". The XPath expression `//element/@*` will give you all the attributes of elements `element`, and with the attributes, their values.