# Get the Element Name From Attribute Value Using Xpath

Tags: python, xml, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to get the element/tag name of each node where I have a particular attribute value.

I have an xml:

```
<a node='1'>This</a>
<b node='2'>Is</b>
<c node='23'>A</c>
<d selector='g'>Loud</d>
<e node='4'>Dog</e>
```

I have a list of nodes of info I want to collect called `nodes`.

I select the text from these nodes with:

```
for node in nodes:
   get_text = response.xpath(f'//*[@node="{node}"]//text()').extract()
```

And I also want the names of the elements of the nodes. However, when I use this line within the same for-loop:

```
get_name = response.xpath(f'//*[@node="{node}"]/name()').get()
```

I get error:

```
ValueError: XPath error: Invalid expression
```

I have tried many variations, but am unable to get the element/tag names of each node.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32796178/2834978

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way that I know how to get the names of the element tags is to use scrapy built in regex method `re`.

The pattern i typicall use is `r'<(\w+)\s'`.

Here is an example:

`scrapy shell`

```py
In [1]: markup = """<html><a node='1'>This</a>
   ...: <b node='2'>Is</b>
   ...: <c node='23'>A</c>
   ...: <d selector='g'>Loud</d>
   ...: <e node='4'>Dog</e></html>"""

In [2]: sel = scrapy.Selector(text=markup)

In [3]: sel.xpath('//*[@node]').re('<(\w+)\s')
Out[3]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']
```

- In the above example I take the markup from your the example you provided and wrap it in a parent tag.
- I then use that to create a scrapy selector object.
- then I run an xpath query to get all elements that have the `node` attribute
- then use the `.re` method to search for the regex pattern to find the element tag name.
- the output is a list of all the element tag names that contain the node attribute.